# Attach Database as a connection string

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So I have this application that I created via VB.NET, Its a Stand Alone Application , During the Development I was setting the app connection string Data source to a Microsoft SQL Server, if the app was only used by me I wouldn't have any problem , my problem is that I want to install it on other Computers , I tried the Attach Database Method , But when I run my application it generates this exception "the user instance login flag is not supported on this version of sql server , the connection will be closed" , I've searched the internet and found out that Attaching Database File is only supported by sql server Express , I have two questions :

If I have SqlLocalDB installed , the attach Database file thing should be working right ?

if i'm wrong , Can you please how can I installed the app with its database without the need to install SQL Server Management studio and attach the database manually so that I could get my app working ?

Comment: I'm a huge Sql Server fan, but it's an awful DB choice for a standalone application such as what you describe here. Sql Server is meant to run as a _server_ on _dedicated hardware_, and wants to _use all the resources_ on the machine where it runs. You should look into an **In-process** database engine instead, such as Sql Server Compact Edition, Sqlite, Firebird, VistaDB, or even MS Access. Any of those would be a better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/304489/Error-msg-the-user-instance-login-flag-is-not-supp

> "If you're not using Express with SQL" ... "then you cannot use user instances. You can create the database manually first and set the connection string to point to that database. Remeber to take away the user instance specification from the connection string."

And if you need help with the LocalDB connection string, you can search this page for "LocalDB":
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/